# asp:button not firing server function on second click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, bootstrap-modal, aspbutton

I have an asp:button:

`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnschedule" Text="Schedule" OnClick="btnschedule_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default custom-button" />`

On click of the button following function is called:

```
protected void btnschedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtcertcode.Text == "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showTrainingScheduleModal('courseErr');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in chk_ModeList.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    pnlschedule.Visible = true;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showTrainingScheduleModal();", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showTrainingScheduleModal('chkErr');", true);
                }
            }
            dt_sch.Clear();
            grdviewschedule_training.DataSource = null;
            grdviewschedule_training.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

In the code

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showTrainingScheduleModal('chkErr');", true);`

the javascript function is opening a bootstrap modal

The issue is on first click the bootstrap modal opens but when I close the modal and again click the button then nothing happens.

The actual working should be like on every click of the button modal should open.

**Any help is appretiated.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Have you added ajax scriptManager ??

Comment: I have added a ScriptManager and I dont know whether its AJAX or not. You can see in the code above. `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showTrainingScheduleModal('chkErr');", true);`

Comment: may be this is postback issue.. check ispostback true